# Android Dialog with dynamic text (API level < 8) killed on rotation

Tags: android, dialog, orientation, rotation

I want to create a dialog with a string that I build at runtime.  It looks like API level 8 allows you to call showDialog with a bundle, but I have to write an app that will run on the older OSs.

How do I create a dialog with something like a simple error string and make sure it doesn't die when I rotate the screen.

I realize if I override onCreateDialog, it will do it for me.  The problem is, this just takes the int constant.  I need to pass a string to it so it knows what to put in the dialog.

If I build my dialog myself and then call .show() on it, it won't live through a screen orientation change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting API Level <8, then it's sort of a pain.

1. Set the string message to a **property on your Activity**
2. Use **onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** and **onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)** to manage your property through configuration changes (such as re-orientation)
3. In **onPrepareDialog(int, Dialog)**, set the message of the dialog to this property. If you don't set this in onPrepareDialog, it'll re-display the previous dialog (in case your message needs to change between dialogs.)

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save dialog message
    if(dialogMessage != null) {
        outState.putString(STATE_KEY_DIALOG_MESSAGE, dialogMessage);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Load dialog message
    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_KEY_DIALOG_MESSAGE)) {
        dialogMessage = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_KEY_DIALOG_MESSAGE);
    }
}

/** onCreateDialog as normal **/

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_MESSAGE:

        // Decorate dialog appropriately
        AlertDialog messageDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
        messageDialog.setMessage(dialogMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is sort of what I've hacked together to get things done, but I find it quite painful.  I ended up writing a parent activity class that will create the dialogs for you, hold the message through an orientation change and recreate the dialogs too.  Unfortunately, this still feels like something we all shouldn't have to do in our apps.  Actually, it seems like a lot of people just don't bother with it and the dialogs disappear after an orientation change.  Then again, I have notice the apps from Google handle the orientation change and the dialogs don't disappear.  This changed in API Lev 8?

Comment: Yes. As of API Level 8, [showDialog(int, Bundle args)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is made available, which allows you to include additional data with the request to show dialog.

Answer (score -1):

You could just pass the string in the constructor.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyDialog(Context context, String msg) {
        super(context);
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(msg);
        setContentView(textView);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't pass the string into the showDialog(int).  If I'm in a method that makes calls to something like a web service and it returns to me an error message, how do I get that error message into MyDialog?  If I call showDialog(int), all I can do is pass the dialogs identifier.  I don't want to do something hacky like push the error message into a static string and hope that it's still OK when onCreateDialog is fired so that it can pick up the string.  If I create my own dialog and then call show() on it, it won't get recreated after a screen orientation change unless I stash it.